# Storing dates in mysql: Performance comparison between various methods for Date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause

Now there are three options that I have in my mind.

**1st** -> four columns(date, month, year, day) => 28, 03, 2011, 1
I can easily search and modify these columns without additional learning of mysql dates.

**2nd** -> one Date column(dd-mm-yyyy) => 28-03-2011
This only requires one column, easier to manage as there is only one WHERE parameter for searching dates. But I dont know how can I search all the records for say a particular day. Lets say all the data for all the mondays in the past or all the data for all the 28ths.

**3rd** -> two columns(unix timestamp for todays date, day) => 1827328721, 1
Now, here I can store store the data as a time stamp and easily do searches and comparisons by simple getting a date and then turning it into a unix timestamp and then using that in the sql. For day I can use the day column.

Now the **questions** are:

1. How does the performance differ between these methods?
2. How would the queries for selects, inserts and updates be constructed for these different proposed solutions?
3. Which one is best in your opinion and why?

Please answer all the three questions thoroughly. Because I can not find this information elsewhere, and I know stack overflow has brilliant programmers who can answer this very coherently. This question will not only benefit a newbie like me but think of all the other newbies who could use this for reference.

Thanking in advance to Stack overflow Community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does the performance differ between these methods?

This will vary greatly based on what type of application is using the database.

The first method could be considered a de-normalized approach, but this could be a good idea if the data is used for an OLAP application.  For example, if you frequently need to gather massive sets of data for a specific day of the month, then this de-normalization could be justified... otherwise, it would just be a waste of storage and needlessly complex.

The same with the third option... it's just a de-normalized representation of the date; it could be justified in very limited uses, but usually it would be a bad idea.

--EDIT--

By De-normalized, I mean the following...

Let's say you have a record with the following fields...

```
Date       Day    Month    Year
3/28/2011  28     3        2011
```

And lets say you need to change the day from the 28th to the 29th.  In this case, you need to update two fields, both the Date and the Day field... instead of just one.  If you always remember to update both, then it isn't a huge problem.  But if you don't, over time you end up with something like the following.

```
Date       Day    Month    Year
3/28/2011  29     2        2009
```

So what's the actual date?  By storing the information in a single place, you eliminate the possibility of inconsistencies in the data.

-- END EDIT--

> Which one is best in your opinion and why?

Unless your database is used for OLAP... I would consider the second option to be the best.

> How would the queries for selects, inserts and updates be
>   constructed for these different
>   proposed solutions?

For the preferred, second option, this is trivial.

-- SECOND EDIT --

You can pass in the date as a string, and MySQL will parse it according.  The date format is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS", but you don't have to specify the time if you don't care to store it.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (date) VALUES ('2011-3-28')
```

Or, if you just want to add the current date...

```
INSERT INTO tablename (date) VALUES (CURDATE() )
```

-- END EDIT --

Comment: Great answer there...thanks...The application that I have is a widget which displays a few elements. Each element's impression is recorded resulting in an insert. so if there are 500 elements in the widget that is 500 inserts...Then to view the stats it would be for today, past few days, some other random day as per requirement. Would you say it is a OLAP application. I for some reason find the first way no so needlessly complex because for inserts you just specify three parameters for the date, month and year; searching being the same. Could you please explain why this is denormalized.

Comment: From your description, your application sounds more like an OLTP than an OLAP application... I would consider a typical OLAP application to be dealing with at least millions of rows of data.  As far as the first way... I would consider it denormalized because the same piece of information (The date) is duplicated in multiple fields... the month, year, and day fields are all already represented in the date column.  If you ever need to modify the date, you would need to modify the data in more than one place to keep it consistent.

Comment: It has about 300,000 records currently and about 1200 inserts/updates happen per second and 500 selects per second on this table.

Comment: The main thing is that being able to update the records for todays date is crucial. Selecting todays date is also important. Doing the stats and reporting on past is not so important and that can be slowed down. But the inserts/updates and selects should be very fast. What is faster-> using three where's statements on three indexed columns or using one where on one indexed date column. Could you also explain what did you mean by three columns for date being a de-nominalized form of storage? Dayummm, you know so much....

Comment: I am only storing date (example today's date 28th), month (today's month march), year (today's year 2011), day (today's day (monday or "1")), Not storing the whole date. Will this be a better method if I use this? Thanks for giving a better explanation about denormalisation. Sorry if I confused you with the usage of the word "Date"

Comment: Ahh.. Thanks for the clarification.  In this case, I would still go with the second option.  As far as which would be faster, the first or second option - As long as they are indexed, both would be fast, but my guess would be that the second option with the atual date would be *slightly* faster, since the index would be more selective.  Also, if you ever needed to do any type of manipulation on the date, like add one week to the date, it would be much easier to do this with a single date column than multiple columns.

Comment: The thing is that I have never used built in date column type in MySQL ever before and there aren't many decent links around for learning more about it. The MySQL documentation could be great but it is definitely not for first time learners. I just need to know how I could perform basic functions such as inserting in todays date, updating in todays date, selecting in todays and past dates. Nothing more....If you know any decent places where I can learn this please help me with link...Although, thanks, you have been a great help and cleared my head on mysql dates.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to store date values, `date` (or `datetime`) type is your choice. Mysql has many [datetime functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) that help you building queries. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE date_column < DATE(NOW()) AND DAYOFWEEK(date_column) = 2
```

// all Mondays in the past

Comment: It is.  Sorry, didn't see it.

Comment: Can you please answer the performance bit of the question, that is crucial! Thanks :)

Comment: Performance depends on indexes and how they correspond to the queries. If you create an index on `date` column, mysql engine will use it once it decides that query can benefit from using index. If you create a separate column for day of week or day of month and an index on that column, this index won't be selective enough to be considered by optimizer

Answer (score 1):

1. Only useful if you need those
   parts independently, which is
   unlikely.
2. Date or Datetime is native and you can make them an index to speed up.
3. not good, not native for mysql. if you need resolution down to seconds, then use datetime.

For more information on operating with date and datetime have a look at the manual.